# Repairing siding, old nails

Tags: painting, preparation

While cleaning and scraping cedar siding prior to painting, I'm noticing that the siding was installed with nails, but as the siding approaches the eves, where it was more difficult to hammer the nails due to low clearance, the carpenters got lazy and a lot of the nail heads are proud of the cedar by 1/16 inch or more. Would a palm nailer be an efficient way to hammer hundreds of these nails in just a little deeper?

Answer (score 1):

I would certainly think a palm nailer should work. A hammer should also work.

Is it possible that the nails were originally nailed flush but they have released and moved outward? If that is the case, then probably there would be no resistance when tapped lightly with a hammer or even pushed.

If there is resistance, then that would indicate the nails were never driven flush. Probably they were driven with a power nailer set a little too soft.